# High Sierra disk space issues

Tags: macos, hard-drive, storage, high-sierra

Am I missing something with my hard drive space? I'm running macOS High Sierra 10.13.1 on my MacBook Pro and trying to clear some disk space to install something.

Disk info says I have 30 GB free out of 250 GB. When I analyse the disk, I'm hardly using any space at all.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a high Sierra Bug it is not even fixed in the latest software update which is 10.3.1 I guess. I have the latest version installed and ever tim it shows that system uses up 40GB even though I have 20GB worth of hoots it always shows 0KB. So I don't know how to fix this but hope that another software update fixes this.Try running `df` in terminal located in Applications>Utilities it should work because it works fine for me.

Comment: @Merm's answer freed up approximately 20GB of storage for me, but it does appear there is still a serious issue on 250GB HD (knowing how Apple works on trying to force new purchases, probably intentional). It appears core files take ~170GB of storage, most of these cannot easily be removed manually and aren't being used... giving 80GB of actual storage space when using High Sierra 10.3+

Answer (score 2):

After contacting Apple, they suggested to book into safe boot, and then reboot into normal mode. This apparently clears some caches and appeared to resolve my problem

1. Reboot the Mac
2. As soon as it reboots, hold the shift key until the login menu appears
3. Login to your normal account and use for about 5-10 mins
4. Reboot and login as normal